# How to remove br and p tags from bbPress

Tags: bbpress

bbPress is giving me a headache trying to figure out how to remove `<br>` and `<p>` tags from existing post in the database after an import. I have tried editing "formatting.php" but with no results except to hide all my forum posts for a day. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in here, not sure if this will accomplish what you're looking to do (the existing posts) but it should stem the tide going forward:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

You're looking for something like this I think:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

This plugin also does something like that, though I've never used it:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpautop-control/